# Export list from Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, data-export

We have a Reactivation Journey targeting inactive customers. I want to export a list of customers who have not been reactivated by the end of the Journey so I can pass on csv file to our Outbound team to contact by telephone.

Is there a way to automatically export that file within the journey? Or is this something that would have to be done externally from the journey?

Answer (score 2):

It’s not possible to automate an export from Journey Builder, but you could use the Update Contact activity to add all subscribers who haven’t reactivated to a Data Extension, and then either export the csv manually or use Automation Studio to export and send it in email automatically, eg. at the end of each day.

Read more here:

Update Contact activity https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_use_the_update_contact_data_activity.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null

Data Extension extract https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_create_a_data_extract_file.htm&type=5

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think it was possible but will give that solution a try!